# Setting Seek Bar with media player

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer, android-seekbar

I am trying to add an audio file to seekbar which will be controlled by seekbar without adding any buttons to my application. The audio file will be attached to seekbar and by seekbar progress, a volume will increase or decrease. Below is my code and my app is crashing, again and again, I don't know why. Kindly help me in this regard.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

   private var mediaPlayer  : MediaPlayer? = null
    private var runnable : Runnable? = null
    private var handler : Handler? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val start = findViewById<Button>(R.id.start)
        val seekbar = findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.seekBar)

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.lowest_frequency)
        mediaPlayer!!.setOnPreparedListener { mediaPlayer ->
            seekbar.max = mediaPlayer.duration
            mediaPlayer.start()
            changeSeekBar()
        }
        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{
            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {

            }

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {
                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

            override fun onProgressChanged(p0: SeekBar?, p1: Int, p2: Boolean) {
                if (p2){
                    mediaPlayer!!.seekTo(p1)
                }
            }

        })

        start.setOnClickListener{
            startActivity(Intent(this,StartActivity::class.java))
        }


    }

    private fun changeSeekBar() {
        seekBar.progress = mediaPlayer!!.currentPosition
        if (mediaPlayer!!.isPlaying){
            runnable = Runnable{
                changeSeekBar()


        }
            handler!!.postDelayed(runnable,50)
            handler!!.postDelayed(runnable,0)
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my logcat error

```
09-24 10:49:58.508 15907-15929/? E/libmtp: [mtp_init_device_info : 0586] -->[mtp_init_device_info  586]Error opening file /data/misc/radio/ahrh,(fd<0) IMEI [
    000000000000000
    ]
09-24 10:49:58.543 15907-15931/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) Process .MtpApplication : Pid (15907) Uid (1000) Euid (1000) Gid (1000) Egid (1000)
    (1) osStat failed "/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db" due to error (2)
    (1) osStat failed "/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases" due to error (2)
    (1) Stat of /data/data/com.android.providers.settings : st_mode(40700) st_uid(1000) st_gid(1000) st_ino(65726)
    (1) Stat of /data/data : st_mode(40771) st_uid(1000) st_gid(1000) st_ino(12)
    (1) Stat of /data : st_mode(40771) st_uid(1000) st_gid(1000) st_ino(2)
    (21) API call with unopened database connection pointer
    (21) misuse at line 119179 of [605907e73a]
09-24 10:51:30.576 6373-6373/? E/BufferItemConsumer: [unnamed-6373-935] Failed to release buffer: Unknown error -1 (1)
09-24 10:51:30.707 6373-6373/? E/BufferItemConsumer: [unnamed-6373-936] Failed to release buffer: Unknown error -1 (1)
09-24 10:51:34.498 16102-16102/? E/Typeface: Error mapping font file /system/fonts/SamsungSans-Num3L.ttf
09-24 10:51:34.499 16102-16102/? E/Typeface: Error mapping font file /system/fonts/SamsungSans-Num3T.ttf
09-24 10:51:34.499 16102-16102/? E/Typeface: Unable to load Family: samsung-sans-num3T:null
    Error mapping font file /system/fonts/SamsungSans-Num4L.ttf
09-24 10:51:34.499 16102-16102/? E/Typeface: Unable to load Family: samsung-sans-num4L:null
    Error mapping font file /system/fonts/SamsungSans-Num4T.ttf
09-24 10:51:34.499 16102-16102/? E/Typeface: Unable to load Family: samsung-sans-num4T:null
    Error mapping font file /system/fonts/SamsungSans-Num35.ttf
09-24 10:51:34.500 16102-16102/? E/Typeface: Error mapping font file /system/fonts/SamsungSans-Num45.ttf
09-24 10:51:34.500 16102-16102/? E/Typeface: Unable to load Family: samsung-sans-num45:null
    Error mapping font file /system/fonts/SamsungSans-Num3Lv.ttf
09-24 10:51:34.500 16102-16102/? E/Typeface: Unable to load Family: samsung-sans-num3LV:null
    Error mapping font file /system/fonts/SamsungSans-Num3R.ttf
09-24 10:51:34.501 16102-16102/? E/Typeface: Error mapping font file /system/fonts/SamsungSans-Num4Tv.ttf
09-24 10:51:34.502 16102-16102/? E/Typeface: Error mapping font file /system/fonts/SamsungSans-Num4Lv.ttf
09-24 10:51:36.101 16231-16231/? E/Typeface: Error mapping font file /system/fonts/SamsungSans-Num3L.ttf
09-24 10:51:36.102 16231-16231/? E/Typeface: Error mapping font file /system/fonts/SamsungSans-Num3T.ttf
09-24 10:51:36.102 16231-16231/? E/Typeface: Unable to load Family: samsung-sans-num3T:null
    Error mapping font file /system/fonts/SamsungSans-Num4L.ttf
09-24 10:51:36.102 16231-16231/? E/Typeface: Unable to load Family: samsung-sans-num4L:null
    Error mapping font file /system/fonts/SamsungSans-Num4T.ttf
09-24 10:51:36.102 16231-16231/? E/Typeface: Unable to load Family: samsung-sans-num4T:null
    Error mapping font file /system/fonts/SamsungSans-Num35.ttf
09-24 10:51:36.103 16231-16231/? E/Typeface: Error mapping font file /system/fonts/SamsungSans-Num45.ttf
09-24 10:51:36.103 16231-16231/? E/Typeface: Unable to load Family: samsung-sans-num45:null
    Error mapping font file /system/fonts/SamsungSans-Num3Lv.ttf
09-24 10:51:36.103 16231-16231/? E/Typeface: Unable to load Family: samsung-sans-num3LV:null
    Error mapping font file /system/fonts/SamsungSans-Num3R.ttf
09-24 10:51:36.103 16231-16231/? E/Typeface: Unable to load Family: samsung-sans-num3R:null
    Error mapping font file /system/fonts/SamsungSans-Num4Tv.ttf
09-24 10:51:36.103 16231-16231/? E/Typeface: Unable to load Family: samsung-sans-num4Tv:null
    Error mapping font file /system/fonts/SamsungSans-Num4Lv.ttf
09-24 10:57:19.587 4405-4422/? E/zygote: Error encountered killing process cgroup uid 99472 pid 15122: No such file or directory
```

Comment: *`my app is crashing, again and again`* Than your need to share that crash log with question Have a look **[Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)**

Comment: please share crash logs

Comment: You have a made a recursive call to changeSeekbar() method while it does nothing just a post delayed call. You are not even updating your seekbar in that method

Comment: @VivekMishra how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MediaPlayer mp;
    SeekBar seekBar;
    Handler mHandler;
    Runnable runnable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mHandler=new Handler();

        seekBar=findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

        mp=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.ed);
        final int Duration=mp.getDuration();
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                seekBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
                updateSeekBar();
                mp.start();
            }
        });


        runnable=new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    updateSeekBar();
    }
    };

//Seekbar Listener

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                mp.seekTo(progress);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

    }
//update method

    private void updateSeekBar() {
        seekBar.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());
        mHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);

    }
}
```